# SQL OLE DB Driver msoledbsql.msi will not install

Tags: sql-server, installation, oledb

I need to install the latest OLE DB driver for SQL Server. When I run the installer I get a message to install the Visual C++ runtime version 14.34 at minimum. I have this version 14.34.31938 installed, yet still I get the message

[image: OLE DB installer fail]

I have tried running the installer as Admin, still the same result

Can you suggest a solution, please?

Comment: Did you install from `vc_redist.x86.exe` or from `vc_redist.x64.exe`? The former is a 32 bit installation only.

Comment: I installed the 64bit and no problems with vc_redist.x64.exe. if I run it again I get the option to uninstall or repair, so it seems that has installed correctly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Apparently a bug in the OLE DB 64-bit installer is that it looks for the 32-bit installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, tried removing all Visual C++ redistributables and installing only 14.26.32532;  no luck. Was using OLD DB Driver 19 for SQL Server x64; so I had only installed the 64bit bit C++ redistributable.

I installed the 32 bit C++ redistributable package and the OLD DB Driver installed.

Yes, I confirmed that I had downloaded the msolddbsql.msi for 64bit.

This did not work:

[image]

This did:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to download both x86 and x64 of visual c++ Redistributable, then restart the computer. It will work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA92O.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This resolved my issue, simply installing one was not sufficient both were necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have a previous version of msoledbsql, from 11 October 2019, so we removed all installed versions of vc_redist, install the latest (14.36) and then my old msoledbsql was installed successfully.